# Spring mass system (rigid body supported by 2 lineair springs)

Tags: mass, spring, linear-systems

[image]

In the figure a beam supported by 2 springs with a different stiffness. Gravitation and friction can be neglected. The position and attitude of the system is defined by coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $sin(\theta)$=$\theta$.

If I'm correct the vertical motion of the center of mass of this particular system is defined as:

\begin{equation*}
    m\ddot x_1+m\ddot x_2=-k_{1}x_{1}-k_{2}x_{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    m\ddot x_1+m\ddot x_2+k_{1}x_{1}+k_{2}x_{2}=0
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
    \ddot x_1+\ddot x_2+\frac{k_{1}}{m}x_{1}+\frac{k_{2}}{m}x_{2}=0 \label{vert}
\end{equation}

And what is then the equation for the rotation? Would that then be:

\begin{equation}
     \ddot\theta_1\frac{b}{2}+\ddot\theta_2\frac{b}{2}+\frac{k_{1}}{m}\theta_1\frac{b}{2}+\frac{k_{2}}{m}\theta_2\frac{b}{2}=0 \label{rot}
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have $\theta =\theta_1 = \theta_2$. The system has two degrees of freedom. The displacement of the center of mass and the title angle. All equations need to be expressed in terms of those two DOF variables. What is missing from the above is the location of the center of mass and the MMOI definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the center of mass at $c= \frac{b}{2}$ and its displacement $$x_c = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$$ The slope of the body is $$\theta  = \frac{x_2-x_1}{b}$$

These two are the degrees of freedom of the body. The equations are transformed to use these variables with $$\begin{align} x_1 & = x_c - \frac{b}{2} \theta \\ x_2 &= x_c + \frac{b}{2} \theta \end{align}$$

The force on each spring is $F_1 =-k_1 x_1$ and $F_2 =-k_2 x_2$. The equations of motion are derived from the sum of forces on body and sum of moments on the center of mass

$$ \left. \begin{aligned}
   F_1 + F_2 &= m \ddot{x}_c \\
   \frac{b}{2} F_2 - \frac{b}{2} F_1 & = I \ddot{\theta}
\end{aligned} \right\} \begin{aligned}
   -(k_1+ k_2) x_c - \frac{b}{2}(k_2-k_1) \theta &= m \ddot{x}_c \\
   -\frac{b}{2} \left( (k_2-k_1) x_c + \frac{b}{2} (k_1+k_2) \theta \right) & = I \ddot{\theta}
\end{aligned} $$

Now collect the terms to get the differential equation

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \ddot{x}_c \\ \ddot{\theta} \end{pmatrix} =
- \begin{vmatrix} \frac{k_1+k_2}{m} & \frac{ \frac{b}{2} (k_2-k_1)}{m} \\
\frac{ \frac{b}{2} (k_2-k_1)}{I} & \frac{ \left( \frac{b}{2} \right)^2 (k_1+k_2)}{I} \end{vmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_c \\ \theta \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thanks! But I first need to express the force and moment equation in coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ and the next step is to express $x_2$ as $x_1$ and $\theta$. This because I need to look at the deflection of spring 1 and the rotation angle of the beam. And sorry that I forget to tell this in advance!

Comment: Sure, then just substitute $x_c = x_1 + \frac{b}{2} \theta$ and $\ddot{x}_c = \ddot{x}_1 + \frac{b}{2}\ddot{ \theta}$  in the above equations.

Comment: So far I substituted $x_c$ but not $\ddot x_c$ since both equations are then a function of $\ddot\theta$ and I then have no idea to make 1 matrix as you did in the end. While I was able to to this by keepin $x_c$.

Comment: I thought you did not want $x_c$ but $x_1$ in the equations of motion. If you change to $x_1$ you _have to_ also change to $\ddot{x}_1$. There is no shortcuts here. The equations should look like $$ \begin{aligned}
   -(k_1+ k_2)  \left(x_1 + \frac{b}{2} \theta \right)- \frac{b}{2}(k_2-k_1) \theta &= m  \left(\ddot{x}_1 + \frac{b}{2} \ddot{\theta} \right)\\
   -\frac{b}{2} \left( (k_2-k_1) \left(x_1 + \frac{b}{2} \theta \right) + \frac{b}{2} (k_1+k_2) \theta \right) & = I \ddot{\theta}
\end{aligned} $$

You still have two equations that you need to solve for the two unknown accelerations.

Comment: Yeah that is what I had. But the how to collect the terms as you did above with $\ddot x_c$ and $\ddot\theta$? That is where I get stuck.. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Solve the two equations for $\ddot{x}_1$ and $\ddot{\theta}$ and extract the coefficients of ${x}_1$ and ${\theta}$. The solution will have the form $$\ddot{x}_1 = -(A  x_1 + B \theta) \\ \ddot{\theta} =-(C x_1 + D \theta)$$ The coefficients $\begin{vmatrix}A &B\\ C & D \end{vmatrix}$ with make up the matrix you are asking for.