# Rigid Body and Two-Spring System and the Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Suppose I had a $2D$ beam with a spring placed on either end of the beam. The spring constants would are $k_1$ and $k_2$, the distance between the left spring and the COM is $d_1$ and the the distance between the right spring and the COM is $d_2$. The COM and the spring constants are configured such that the beam is perfectly level at rest. I'm attempting to derive the equations of motion of the system, but I am wondering if two of my assumptions are correct: the system will always rotate around the COM and not some other point, **and** that this rotation does not increase or decrease the gravitational potential energy of the system if there is no translation of the COM.

I've use the Lagrangian, and wanted to make sure that this Lagrangian is correct. Let $x$ be the vertical position of the COM and let $\theta$ be the angle between the $d_1$ line (essentially the difference of angle between the COM-left end at rest and the COM-left end not at rest).

**Kinetic Energy** 
 
I think this is simple enough: just the kinetic energy of the COM, $\frac{1}{2}m\frac{dx}{dt}^2$ and the rotational kinetic energy about the COM, $\frac{1}{2}I\frac{dθ}{dt}^2$.

**Potential Energy** 
 
This is a little bit more difficult. There should obviously be the gravitational potential energy, $mgx$.

The left spring will have a potential energy of $\frac{1}{2}k_1x_1^2$ where $x_1$ is the displacement. From what I see, the spring is compressed in two different ways: from the COM moving up and down and from the angle of the beam changing. So that $x_1 = x + d_1\tan{\theta}$. For the right spring, as $\theta$ increases, it becomes compressed meaning that $x_2 = x - d_2\tan{\theta}$.

**Lagrangian** 
So, in total, the Lagrangian would be:

$$\mathscr{L} =\frac{1}{2}m\frac{dx}{dt}^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\frac{dθ}{dt}^2 - \frac{1}{2}k_1(x+d_1\tan{\theta})^2 - \frac{1}{2}k_2(x-d_2\tan{\theta})^2 - mgx$$

I am skeptical that this is correct. The following question is similar yet the derived equations that I am getting are somewhat different: [Spring mass system (rigid body supported by 2 lineair springs)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/320152/spring-mass-system-rigid-body-supported-by-2-lineair-springs)

**Edit**
I am also realizing, is the initial compression of the springs at rest, ie the energy stored in the springs, important. Did I forget something by not considering this?

Comment: Concerning the difference between your setup and the previous question: to the extent that the attachment points are only moving vertically, with no horizontal motion, you will have $\theta \ll 1$ and so $\tan \theta \approx \theta$.  This will simplify your life somewhat.

Comment: Yes, I agree. There will be no displacement of the beam in any direction besides the x direction. I have also used the small angle formula as you mentioned and solves these differential equations. I'm mainly concerned about this set up modeling the problem correctly and why my answer differs.

Comment: Writing down the Lagrangian, the initial compression does not play a role. This will only be used (as an initial value) once you start to solve the differential equations...

Comment: Ok I will have to think on this to confirm it in my mind.

Comment: @kricheli, I think I may have an issue with my variables. When x = 0,  = 0, then the potential energy within the springs would be 0. This is necessarily true as the springs are compressed.

Comment: the coordinate system must be at the  center of mass

Comment: @Eli could you please elaborate?

Comment: You would take $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be deviations from the equilibrium of the spring, not from the (maybe compressed) initial position, and then I don't see how the compressed initial conditions pose a problem.

Comment: @AlexVaughan the beam moment of inertia $~I~$ is given at the CM. also choose right hand coordinate system x to the right y to the top and z to your face, thus the rotation $~\theta~$ is about the z axis

Comment: So, in the system equilibrium, have the COM at 0,0,0?

Comment: @kricheli Ok so I need to re-calculate what $x_1$ and $x_2$ are?

Comment: No, the calculation is fine. You just need to be aware what $x_1=0$ and $x_2$ mean: the springs being relaxed/in equilibrium without external forces. So when you start with a compressed initial condition, your initial values for the ODE would be some appropriate $x_1 \neq 0$ and $x_2 \neq 0$.