# Vibrational Modes and Centers of Torque

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, spring

This is addendum to the question: [Vibrational Modes and Imaginary Frequencies of a Three Spring System](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/771586/vibrational-modes-and-imaginary-frequencies-of-a-three-spring-system/771642?noredirect=1#comment1732298_771642).

After performing NASTRAN analysis on this problem, it appears that I was incorrect in my assumption that the rotational modes of the system will rotate around the center of gravity. Now, I am trying to rectify this error, but I am having some trouble with this in my model. From what I understand, because of this error, my choice of having $\theta$ as the coordinate for the angle of the orientation of the bar with the COM as the axis is not correct either. With that being said, I believe I should be choosing $\theta$ to be the angle of the orientation from the pivot axis. How would I find this point given all the information I have so far?

Summing the torques indicates that: $-k_1x_1r_1=k_2x_2r_2$ where $x_1, x_2$ represent the compression distance and $r_1, r_2$ represent the distance from the spring forces to the "center of torque". This is my best guess at how to do this, but given that $x_1, x_2$ change with time would imply that the location of this "center of torque" would also change as time goes on which is unexpected.

Any suggestions as to how I should approach this?